# I want to print amount like 2523525252.025 when I using double data type it's changed in 2.523525252025E9 how can fix?

Tags: java, android

I want to print amount like `2523525252.025` when I using double data type it's changed in `2.523525252025E9` how can fix?

**Example -**

```
Double saleprice=145236.12;
int itemqountity=1500;
Double totalamount= saleprice*itemqountity;
Log.e("totalamount",""+totalamount);
```

**output-**

> E/totalamount: 2.1785418E8

Comment: The number is not "changed", internally it's the same number. What you want is to print it in a certain format.

Comment: Hint: you are expected to do some research prior asking questions ...

Answer (score 2):

Please use `DecimalFormat` to print your value without scientific notation here is an example.

```
double test = 12345678; 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#"); 
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); 
System.out.println(df.format(test)); 
//12345678
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(2.523525252025E9);
System.out.println(bigDecimal.toPlainString());
```

Comment: upvode for accurate Answer. But please put some explanation so that other users can easily understand.

Comment: I like more Irfan Babar version. :)